# Store result of range() as a list variable - Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm doing the challenges on Project Euler to get better at python (I am a beginner) and I am trying to do [Problem 9](http://projecteuler.net/problem=9).

```
vara = lista[-1]
varb = listb[-1]
varc = listc[-1]

while not(vara < varb < varc):
listb.pop(-1)
lista.pop(-1)
lista.pop(-1)
if ((vara * vara) + (varb * varb) == varc * varc):
    print vara, varb, varc
else:
listc.pop(-1)
if ((vara * vara) + (varb * varb) == varc * varc):
    print vara, varb, varc
else:
    listb.pop(-1)
    if ((vara * vara) + (varb * varb) == varc * varc):
        print vara, varb, varc
    else:
        lista.pop(-1)
```

I have tried many methods to get lista/listb/listc to have the values from 1 - 1000 but none of them really seem to work

```
lista = range(1, 1000)
lista = range[1, 1000]
```

etc

Comment: Protip: Use meaningful names for your variables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To generate values from 1 to 1000 you need to specify the ending value as 1000 **+ 1**, i.e., 1001. So

**Python 2.x**

```
# python 2.x
liasta = range(1, 1001)
```

**Python 3.x**

```
# python 3.x
liasta = list(range(1, 1001))
```

will give you a list of values from 1 to 1000.

[range()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#range) uses a *half-closed interval*, meaning it ***includes*** the first value in the list of values it generates, but ***excludes*** the last one. Note that if you don't specify a starting value, `range()` will default to `0`. You can also specify an increment value, which defaults to `1` unless otherwise specified.

Three examples from the [doc page](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#range):

```
>>> range(10)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

>>> range(1, 11)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

>>> range(0, 30, 5)
[0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25]
```

Comment: It gives the error
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "euler9.py", line 10, in <module>
     lista.pop(-1)
IndexError: pop from empty list :/

Comment: @c3ns0r3d Do you make these calls `lista = range(1, 1001)` etc before your `while` loop? If you create `lista` the way I showed in my answer, you can for sure do `lista.pop(-1)` without troubles.

Comment: @c3ns0r3d Hard to say without seeing all of your current code. The code you have posted is not indented right, and has probably changed. The problem isn't with the list creation or the pop function though.

Comment: @c3ns0r3d I would suggest you try out some list creations and functions interactively in the shell to get a feel for them, and then modify your program accordingly. That's how usually work when I run into some unexpected program behavior. This way you can convince yourself how lists are created and the use of the pop function.

Comment: the indent is correct on notepad++ and that (without the list variables) is my whole code, i tend to just write snippets for these challenges

Comment: @c3ns0r3d I understand about Project Euler, I'm working through the problems myself too :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this for your code :

```
lista = range(1, 1001)
listb = list(lista)
listc = list(lista)
```

Do not do this:

```
lista = listb = listc = range(1, 1001)
```

Because then your `pop`s all work on the same list.

Answer (score 0):

Although your question asks how to make a list of numbers in a range, I'd like to ask you a question back:

> Do you actually need three lists of numbers or do you just need to
>   look *through* the possible values for a solution?

I ask because although you can get to the answer you seek, it isn't best expressed the way you are headed. For example:

```
for c in range(1, 1001):
    for b in range(1, c):
        for a in range(1, b):
             if is_pythagorean_triple(a, b, c):
                 ...

def is__pythagorean_triple(a, b, c):
    ...
```

doesn't create any lists (at least none that you have to think about). Another question is why does `a` only range up to `b`?